# Spaces in the connection string value of an SSIS CommandFile variable value

Tags: ssis, bids, sql-server-data-tools

I am pretty new to SSIS (my first real project) and I have built a package that successfully performs some insert operations on a database. I want to deploy it to multiple environments, so I have created a connection manager whose connection string will be passed in from the command line which will in turn be defined in a command file.

The command that I run from the command line is ...

```
DTExec /F InitialDatabseImport.dtsx /CommandFile InitialCommandFile.config.txt
```

In the command file (InitialCommandFile.config.txt) I have the following variable assignment ...

```
/SET \Package.Variables[User::DBConnectionString].Properties[Value];"\"Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV12;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connect Timeout=30;Auto Translate=False;"\"
```

Running this I get the following error ...

```
Option "Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV12;Initial" is not valid.
```

It seems that is delimiting the connection string on spaces rather than semicolons.

---

I have tried a number of configurations with quotes. Here I changed the quotes in front of "Data" to something that seemed to make more sense  ...

```
/SET \Package.Variables[User::DBConnectionString].Properties[Value];\""Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV12;Initial Catalog=MarketingPrefsDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connect Timeout=30;Auto Translate=False;"\"
```

which returned the error ...

```
The argument "\Package.Variables[User::DBConnectionString].Properties[Value];\"Data" has mismatched quotes.
```

---

And this one, I wrapped the entire assignment in quotes ...

```
/SET "\Package.Variables[User::DBConnectionString].Properties[Value];\"Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV12;Initial Catalog=MarketingPrefsDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connect Timeout=30;Auto Translate=False;\"";
```

which returned the error ...

```
Argument ""\Package.Variables[User::DBConnectionString].Properties[Value];\"Data" for option "set" is not valid.
```

Has anyone else who has seen this problem been able to figure it out?

Thanks,
G

**UPDATE - 2014/07/21**

When I put the SET command directly in the command line I am getting a slightly different error ...

Command Line ...

```
C:\Project>DTExec /F QuaeroInitialImport.dtsx /SET \Package.Variables[User::DBConn
ectionString].Properties[Value];"Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connect Timeout=30;Auto Translate=False;"
```

Error Message

```
Argument ""\Package.Variables[User::DBConnectionString].Properties[Value];\"Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connect Timeout=30;Auto Translate=False;" for option "set" is not valid.
```

Comment: I can't recall the escaping rules at the moment but you're not making balanced double quotes. `;"\"Data Source...False;"\"` Open quote, escape quote, stuff, close quote, escaped quote. I would expect it to be like `;"\"Data Source...False;\""`

Comment: Nah ... I agree that the quote appeared a bit wonky too. That's why I tried a number of quote combinations. I have re-tried your suggestion however just in case I brain-farted but still get the same error. Thanks for the suggestion though. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I've met similar issue and just share my work-around in case others reach here thru google.

My case is:

Deploying the package on SQL Server 2014, and I use some package parameter in the package and met this issue. I've met this if I don't use package parameter on another server running SQL Server 2014 also (both server are running the same version of SQL Server 2014).

I fix this by replacing all spaces in the keywords of the connection space with an underscore (_). The connection work for me on my server like:

Data_Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,xxxx;Initial_Catalog=ABC_DEF;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Persist_Security Info=True;Auto_Translate=False;User_ID=userabc;

Please note even I have forgotten to replace some space in some keyword, it still works.

So I finally change it as below:

Data_Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,xxxx;Initial_Catalog=ABC_DEF;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Persist_Security_Info=True;Auto_Translate=False;User_ID=userabc;

So... it doesn't make me comfortable in this case as I am not sure actually if it is working on a correcting settings... you still have to verify it yourself.